# Db2 iseries INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY

Tags: database, db2, ibm-midrange, db2-400

Does anybody knows if DB2 for i (V6r1) supports something like

```
INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE.
```

I need to do update with joins but don't want to use subqueries.

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to do that with DB2 for i and I didn't see anything in the [documentation](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/db2/rbafzintro.htm).

Comment: What's wrong with sub-queries?

Answer (score 7):

**You can solve this by using 'MERGE'.like this:**

1.**Step One**:table 'TEST' has a table structure (A,B,C) with a prime key 'A', existing a data record(1,2,3).

2.**Step two**:now you can insert a record (1,9,9) by using this SQL command as follows:

```
MERGE INTO TEST AS T
USING (VALUES( 1, 9,  9))  AS DAT(A, B,  C)
ON T.A = DAT.A 
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE  SET T.C = DAT.C
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN  INSERT (A, B,  C)  VALUES (DAT.A, DAT.B, DAT.C)
```

Answer (score 2):

In IBM i v7.1 you will have the new [MERGE statement](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/db2/rbafzmerge.htm)

In v6.1, you can `UPDATE` where a matching row is found, and then another statement to `INSERT` where there is no match.

For example, an update might look like this:

```
    UPDATE targetfile as u                                  
      SET  (  flda,fldb,fldc ) =
        (SELECT  a,   b,   c
                FROM inpdata as i           
                WHERE u.keyfld = i.keyfld
             )
      WHERE u.keyfld IN 
             (SELECT i.keyfld
                FROM inpdata as i           
             );
```

then

```
    INSERT INTO targetfile 
            (keyfld, flda, fldb, fldc)
      SELECT keyfld, a,    b,    c
        FROM inpdata as i
        WHERE i.keyfld  NOT IN 
             (SELECT t.keyfld
                FROM targetfile as t           
             );
```

or

```
    INSERT INTO targetfile 
            (keyfld, flda, fldb, fldc)
      SELECT keyfld, a,    b,    c
        FROM                inpdata    as i
        LEFT EXCEPTION JOIN targetfile as t           
          ON i.keyfld = t.keyfld;
```

Comment: Could You give some examples on this update/insert statements ?

Comment: Note that in the case of the two statements (`UPDATE` and `INSERT`), they must be performed _in that order_, and the **tables** must be locked (given the type of statements being run, the escalation should be automatic under a transaction), or otherwise not accessed for writing by other processes, or you risk data errors.  Still, without the `MERGE` statement, it's the way I'd do it, too (have, for that matter).